# Reading an object via ObjectInputStream throws EOF exception

Tags: java, serialization, file-io, deserialization, objectinputstream

I am trying to read an object via `ObjectInputStream`. However I retrieve the following stacktrace with an `EOFException`:

```
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2325)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2794)
at
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:801)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
at student.operations.StudentOperations.addStudentDetails(StudentOperations.java:46)
at student.
```

My code is the following:

```
FileInputStream fi = new        FileInputStream(file.getPath());
ObjIn = new ObjectInputStream(fi);

FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file.getPath());
Objout = new ObjectOutputStream(fo);

//bo = new BufferedOutputStream(Objout);
//bi = new BufferedInputStream(ObjIn);

System.out.println("Enter the number of students to add");

number = in.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter Student roll number:");
int rollno = in.nextInt();

try {
    HashMap<Integer, StudentModel> hs = (HashMap<Integer, StudentModel>) ObjIn
            .readObject();

    if (hs.containsKey(rollno)) {
        System.out.println("Duplicate values are not allowed ");
    } else {

        for (counter = 0; counter < number; counter++) {

            System.out.println("Enter Student name:");
            String name = in.next();

            System.out.println("Enter Student's Father name:");
            String fname = in.next();

            System.out.println("Enter Gender:");
            String gender = in.next();

            System.out.println("Enter Date of birth:");
            String date = in.next();

            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "dd-MM-yyyy");
            Date dateObj = null;

            try {
                dateObj = dateFormat.parse(date);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

            Calendar birthday = Calendar.getInstance();

            birthday.setTimeInMillis(dateObj.getTime());

            Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();

            long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            current.setTimeInMillis(currentTime);

            int age = current.get(Calendar.YEAR)
                    - birthday.get(Calendar.YEAR);

            System.out.println("Enter the AddressLine1:");
            String address1 = in.next();
            in.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter the AddressLine2:");
            String address2 = in.next();
            in.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter the city");
            String city = in.next();
            in.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter the state");
            String state = in.next();
            in.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter the country:");
            String country = in.next();
            in.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter the Zipcode");
            int code = in.nextInt();
            in.nextLine();

            StudentUtill.student.put(rollno, new StudentModel(name,
                    fname, rollno, age, gender, dateObj, address1,
                    address2, city, state, country, code));

            Objout.writeObject(StudentUtill.student.toString());


            Objout.flush();

        }// for loop ends here
```

tester.StudentTester.main(StudentTester.java:30)

Comment: which line is this? `StudentOperations.java:46`

Comment: If you're getting an EOF most likely you didn't serialize your HashMap correctly in the first place

Comment: @ControlAltDel No. It means he didn't serialize it *at all*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You're trying to read objects from an empty file. Look at the stack trace. End of file trying to read the header. There isn't even a header in the file, let alone an object. It's empty.
- Don't create a `FileOutputStream` until you have something to write to it, and don't forget to close it immediately afterwards.
- You're also incorrectly converting the map to a `String` before writing it to the file, but you haven't yet got to the point where that's a problem.

Comment: could you please explain me how perform object serialization in efficient way.

Comment: @TheRed If you have a new question you should ask it as a new question. Nobody is going to see it down here. I didn't, for two years.

Comment: @Visionwriter 1. I do not agree that there is anything amiss with this answer, or that it corresponds to your description in any way, and specifically I do not agree that actual code would help to explain anything in this question, and in general this is not, and I am not, a free coding service. 2. Continuing searching rather than starting irrelevant conversations or new questions in comments is exactly what the 'poor fellow' is supposed to do on this site. 3. Don't make personal remarks here.