# Install & Run OWASP ZAP via Ubuntu command line

Tags: ubuntu, zap

I'm using a shell script to install & run ZAP on an Ubuntu image.

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install default-jre -y
sudo apt install snapd -y
sudo snap install zaproxy --classic

cd /snap/zaproxy/current
java -jar ./zap-2.11.1.jar -cmd -quickurl https://www.website.com/ -quickprogress -quickout ~/report.xml
```

The Spider works fine, but a little while after the Active Scan starts, it throws the following error:

```
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2822)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:804)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:301)
    at hudson.remoting.ObjectInputStreamEx.<init>(ObjectInputStreamEx.java:49)
    at hudson.remoting.Command.readFrom(Command.java:142)
    at hudson.remoting.Command.readFrom(Command.java:128)
    at hudson.remoting.AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.read(AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.java:35)
    at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:61)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel
    at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:75)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Backing channel 'jenkins-zap-t6s4nu' is disconnected.
```

I saw in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34397815/reading-an-object-via-objectinputstream-throws-eof-exception) that `java.io.EOFException` happens when you try to read an empty file. The shell script works fine when it's running on a PC or VM, so I'm thinking maybe there's a hidden dependency that isn't installed by default on the barebones Ubuntu image.

Is there a portion of this shell script that's missing or incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was with our server, not with ZAP! We had a rogue Jenkins controller that believed it needed to kill all agents it had not started.

If someone else runs into this problem in the future, definitely try running server diagnostics.

Answer (score 2):

Run the below commands to install owasp zap

```
echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/cabelo/xUbuntu_22.10/ /' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:cabelo.list
curl -fsSL https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:cabelo/xUbuntu_22.10/Release.key | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/home_cabelo.gpg > /dev/null
sudo apt update
sudo apt install owasp-zap
```

Comment: where will this get installed, as I am not able to access it

Comment: @AniketKumar /usr/share/owasp-zap/zap.sh

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manually launching the jar try using `zap.sh`

Comment: Looks like the same error happens. It was worth a shot though, thanks!

Comment: That message seems to be from Jenkins not ZAP. Another thing you could try is running without writing a report (incase it's that file handle its having issues with.)

Comment: Okay, I'll remove the `quickout` argument and try it again.

Comment: It looks like that did not work either. Thanks so much for your time though :)

Answer (score 0):

There are official releases from Zap's team themselves, check:
https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home%3Acabelo&package=owasp-zap